# how do I open a file when Vue.js router path is /apple-app-site-association

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, deep-linking

I have a Vuejs project with the following folder structure 
https://ibb.co/dpGPBNw

I would like to open the file named `apple-app-site-association` inside the path `static/config` which is outside my `src` folder, using `vue-router` routing.

That means when a user redirects to `https://myDomain/apple-app-site-association`, the file `static/config/apple-app-site-association` should open up instead of routing to a component (which is how `vue-router` usually handles routing)

I require this for something called as `deep-linking`, i.e when a user navigates to `https://myDomain/apple-app-site-association`, the mobile app should open instead of navigating to the browser.

I do not know exactly how `deep-linking` works, but my mobile-app developer instructed that this is how we can achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Vue router, which is in charge of all routes **within** application, can't redirect you **outside** of it. You can, however, create component, that will only contain this specific document, and then you can point specific route to this component.
Regarding `deep-linking` it only means you get straight at some point within your app and not to the home page.

Comment: How does one create a component that only contains the JSON document?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved:

**Option 1:**

1. Create a component that will open the file:

```
<template>
  <div></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'WellKnown',
  props: {
    file: String
  },
  mounted () {
    window.open(this.file)
  }
}
</script>
```

2. Create a route in your vue router that uses that component and passes the file url:

```
  {
    path: '/.well-known/apple-app-site-association',
    component: WellKnown,
    props: {
      file: '<URL to your file>'
    }
  }
```

3. Deploy your app, whenever you go to `<yourapp>/.well-known/apple-app-site-association` you should be promp to download that file (the expected result)

Thats it.

Notes:

- The component created in step 1 receives the file URL as prop. That prop can be passed from the route definition it self.
- The file can be hosted whereever you want, what's important is that can be accesable from the url you defined in the router.

**Option 2:**
This one is actually more straight forward. Place the file in your public directory:

[image]

And for the `apple-app-site-association` file change the content-type header to `application/pkcs7-mime`. More info [here](https://devdactic.com/universal-links-ionic/)

Hope this makes sense and help others.

Comment: Do i need to simply add `/.well-known/apple-app-site-association` as `<URL to your file>` ? - only pasting it into public folder always redirects me to login page

Comment: Is it possible that you have a redirect in your routing configuration? If you have an authentication guard it could also cause this redirect